# How do you optimise AST's or convert them to a real language

Tags: decompilation, decompiler, ast

I have been interested in automatic vulnerability assessment and decompilation of code for a while now. And as a result I have been building parsers in Python that reads a bin, disassembles it instruction by instruction while tracing the execution (the way IDA does it).

I have been tracing the polluted registers (polluted as in user input) to check when such registers allow us to setup a call or a jump.

This research has grown to the point, where I want to transform it to a decompiler. I had a look at boomerang and other open source decompilers. I have also had a quick peek inside the dragon book (I don't own it). I would like to hear what you guys think about this idea. Below is my outline:

1. Open the binary file to decompile.
2. Detect a filetype (PE or ELF) to select the EP and memory layout.
3. Jump to the EP and follow execution path of the code while disassembling. 
   I use udis86 for it. This execution is in a libemu kind of way.
4. Parse the resulting assembly an middle language. To get
   simpler instructions, (e.g. always remove things like `SHL EAX, 0x02` and
   change those things to `MUL` instructions).
5. Parse it into a Abstract Syntax Tree.
6. Optimize the AST (although, I have no idea how).
7. Transform the AST to something that looks like C.

I am having issues with the last 2 steps. How does someone parse AST to a real language or something that looks like it? How do you optimize ASTs? Are there build C or Python libraries to accomplish it?

Comment: You may be interested in reading the Python source code for the recently released ida-decompiler: https://github.com/EiNSTeiN-/ida-decompiler

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The classic work on the decompilation is Cristina Cifuentes' PhD thesis ["Reverse Compilation Techniques"](http://zyloid.com/recomposer/files/decompilation_thesis.pdf). She describes generation of C code in Chapter 7.

The author of the REC decompiler also has a nice summary about the decompilation process, though it's more informal:

http://www.backerstreet.com/decompiler/introduction.htm

For completeness, here's Ilfak's whitepaper on the Hex-Rays decompiler, though he glances over this specific issue, only mentioning that it's "Very straightforward and easy" :):

http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/ppt/decompilers_and_beyond_white_paper.pdf